# How do you use a Cursor from ole32.dll in a WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, interop, extern

I want to use one of Windows' built-in cursors that are not included in the 'Cursors' class. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49485890/using-the-windows-drag-copy-cursor) to which the answer appears to provide the information I need, but there is a problem. `System.Windows.Input.Cursor` does not have a constructor that accepts `IntPtr`. Here is the code snippet provided by that answer (comment is mine):

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr LoadCursor(IntPtr hInstance, UInt16 lpCursorName);

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var l = LoadLibrary("ole32.dll");
    var h = LoadCursor(l, 6);
    this.Cursor = new Cursor(h);//this does not compile!
}
```

My question is: How can I make a `System.Windows.Input.Cursor` from one of the cursors contained in ole32.dll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out by using the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16048885/how-to-convert-intptr-to-cursor-or-safehandle).

Here is my code:

```
static class WindowsCursors
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr LoadCursor(IntPtr hInstance, UInt16 lpCursorName);

    public static Cursor GetCursor(ushort cursorNumber)
    {
        var library = LoadLibrary("ole32.dll");
        var cursorPointer = LoadCursor(library, cursorNumber);
        return CursorInteropHelper.Create(new SafeCursorHandle(cursorPointer));
    }

    class SafeCursorHandle : Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid
    {
        public SafeCursorHandle(IntPtr handle) : base(true)
        {
            base.SetHandle(handle);
        }
        protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
        {
            if (!this.IsInvalid)
            {
                if (!DestroyCursor(this.handle))
                    throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception();
                this.handle = IntPtr.Zero;
            }
            return true;
        }
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool DestroyCursor(IntPtr handle);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var cursor = WindowsCursors.GetCursor(3);
```